# Angular Material sidenav event broadcasted

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using sidenav directive from Angular Material. When we click out of the component, sidenav will be closed. What is the event broadcasted at that time?

Answer (score 3):

In your `controller` use [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) to check the return value of `isOpen()`:

```
  $scope.$watch(
    function () {
      return $mdSidenav('left').isOpen();
    },
    function (newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log(newValue);
      if (newValue == false) {
        var button = angular.element(document.querySelector('#navButton'))
        button.removeAttr('md-focused')
      }
    });
```

Comment: I have actually tried this. With angular-material-0.10.0 the button does not have an attribute, rather a class called 'md-focused'. I can see it in the Firefox Inspector. But it does not have the 'md-focused' class at the moment the watch handler is executed. Seems there is some sort of timing issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the directive there is a function to detect,

```
self.close  = function() { return self.$toggleOpen( false ); };
```

Here is the  [`SideNav`](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/sidenav/sidenav.js) directive