# Capture event when md-sidenav is toggled (using md-is-locked-open)

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using the [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdSidenav) component framework.

I've defined a page with a md-sidenav called `sidebar` that is automatically shown (on the left of the screen) if resized to a certain width. This is possible thanks to the directive `md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')"`.

What I try to achieve seems quite straightforward: I just want to know (have an event triggered) when the sidenav is being shown / hidden (by user, or automatically). I've tried several different solutions, but nothing seem to be working.

I have a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SqCfJxje8f3wNmTy95VO) that has the same behaviour as what I'm are trying to achieve. In the `activate` function, I try to capture the events (or what I thought would be events, doesn't seem so because it's not working).

I tried almost all the solutions that were given [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/974) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631311/angular-material-sidenav-event-broadcasted), but no luck (specially when automatically showing / hiding the sidenav).

Any ideas here?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `$mdMedia` service in the controller instead of in the view. From the [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdMedia)

> The media query will be re-evaluated on resize, allowing you to register a watch.

So you can register a watcher for your desired media query size, then call a function when the watcher fires:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){return $mdMedia('gt-sm');}, function(){
    $scope.showSideNav = !$scope.showSideNav;
    console.log("SideNav State Change");
});
```

Then I'd setup the sideNav like this:

```
md-is-locked-open="showSideNav"
```

Here is a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9wSIQZXbM0ieZfHi3yTZ?p=preview), forked from your Plunker

Comment: Thanks! That could be an option to control that behaviour. Although it's a shame to have to do it this way when there's a $mdSidenav service that could provide an easier (and more centralized) way of doing these things. I'm going to check if I can adapt it to our needs.

Comment: There could be another solution by adding a watcher on some component of the `$mdSidenav` service, however still using a manual watcher and still a bit clunky. Sounds like the making for a good pull-request.

Comment: Turns out the $mdMedia event is being fired _before_ the sidenav is hidden / showed. I could put a timeout to wait, but it's all getting quite dirty.